# Кастомный SIP клиент для Android

Tags: java, android, sip

есть задача: нужно в существующее приложение добавить функционал сип клиента (работа через все сети 2g/3g/4g/wifi), работа в фоне. Рассматривал csipsimple, но по нему мало информации и примеров. Какую библиотеку выбрать? (сип встроенный в андроид не подходит поскольку нестабильно работает с 3g)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [pjsip](https://www.pjsip.org) и на ее основе https://github.com/VoIPGRID .